# how to convert html page to excel using html code

Tags: javascript, html, ms-word

how to convert html page to excel using html code

Comment: You want to convert HTML with HTML?

Comment: export html table content to excel using javascript code

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  You would need to use a [server-side language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting#Examples).

Comment: JavaScript is generally client-side and does and for more than one reason isn't suitable.

Answer (score 1):

HTML is not a programming language, it's a markup language (hence the name). Therefore, it will not be able to convert anything to any other format, including excel.

The easiest way to accomplish what you're looking for would be to convert that HTML page to a comma separated format in some fashion, as many programming languages can parse a CSV format, and Excel can import a CSV file and create a spreadsheet from it.